# Change the default tick axis in histogram matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I use matplotlib , with the code

```
Number = [ 10, 20, 30, 40 , 50 10 , 20, 10 , 100]

Plthist(number, 10 , range(0, 100))
```

The result that i got for x axis is `0 20 40 60 80 90`

I want change the tick of x axis into `0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xticks` function of the library to achieve this. A snippet is attached below:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.xticks(ticks=np.linspace(0, 80, 9))
plt.hist(number, 10, range(100))
```